# magento 2 logo image cant upload

Tags: magento2, admin, image-upload, transactional-mail, logo

Hi I'm facing trouble in uploading the logo image in the transaction email section using admin back-end, it is still showing the previous one but with some block and the resolution showed "x". May I know the cause of this and how can I solve it?

Comment: You have to static content deploy after uploading the image  using `php bin/magento setup:static-content:`deploy

Comment: @AmitBera i tried and it doesnt work

Comment: Are you facing any error then post it here & the second thing is that does the new logo is appearing in the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Methods:

1) Try to upload through Admin panel.

2) Try to upload through magento root folder.

Use Command:

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: i tried using both command and it doesnt work :/